# Can a xmr proxy mine without a pool?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, solo-mining, pool-mining

I have several computers at home. I can join all of them through a xmr proxy to be seen as a user but I have been told that to mine I need to join a pool. I know the advantages of mining through a pool but I want to try solo mining.

Can some computers going through a xmr proxy (seen as just one user) solo mine XMR without a pool?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *proxy* doesn't mine. You also don't need a pool to mine. A pool *proxy* needs a pool.

If you want to solo mine with a collection of your own computers, you have a couple of options. You could set up your own *private* pool or use XMRig on each computer and connect them directly to your own Monero daemon. Both of these options effectively have you solo mining with a bunch of your own computers.

Comment: Thansk for your answser. I know a proxy doesn't mine, it just gathers miners behind it and pressents it as one user to the outside.Anyway, you said a pool proxy needs a pool. I haven't heard about this tearm in all hours I have been looking for info. Is xmrig-proxy a proxy pool? From your answer I understand that all proxies are created to be connected to a pool, am I right? I thought a pool was just important join the miners force and make mining easier, and of course share the revenue.As I did not want to share revenue I thought a xmrig-proxy would be enough connecting it directly to a node.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you mean when you said "connect it to your daemon". Perhaps I could have the 3 computers connected to the proxy and then the proxy directly to the daemon? This will make the pool innecesarie. Did I say anything stupid?

Comment: If you decide to go for your own pool, I'd like to recommend [monero-pool](https://github.com/jtgrassie/monero-pool) it's insanely simple to set up, and run.

Comment: @Notbad "you said a pool proxy needs a pool" <- xmrig-proxy connects to a pool, thus needs a pool. "Is xmrig-proxy a proxy pool?" <- No. It's a pool proxy. It proxies miners to a pool. "As I did not want to share revenue I thought a xmrig-proxy would be enough connecting it directly to a node" <- No. a proxy doesn't help here because a proxy connects to a *pool*, not a node. So unless that pool is private (which negates the need or a proxy in the first place), xmrrig-proxy doesnt help here.

Comment: @Notbad "Perhaps this is what you mean when you said connect it to your daemon" <- No. I said connect XMRig (not xmrig-proxy) to your daemon. XMRig is a miner that can connect to a pool, a proxy, OR directly to a daemon. The latter of which I was suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

when I went to the latest mining at xmr rig, it had me set up a mining wallet and started mining. I was trying to join a pool, I went online at xmrpool.org and after I chose a  pool to join, I didn't see where to actually input my information. I think that the program just started going through the process alone.